# Monster equipped with 2 Safe Zone then 1 of them is destroyed

Tags: yu-gi-oh

**Q1-** If I activated 2 [Safe Zone](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Safe_Zone) cards on **my** monster, then if one of them (the 2 Safe Zone cards) is destroyed:

- The monster won't be destroyed because it's still protected by the other Safe Zone..?
- Or, the monster will be destroyed because the undestroyed Safe Zone's effect protects against opponent's card effects only, while the destroyed Safe Zone is my own card's effect..?

**Q2-** I activated 2 Safe Zone on **my opponent's** monster, then one of them (the 2 Safe Zone cards) is destroyed, then all 3 cards are destroyed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Activate this card by targeting 1 face-up Attack Position monster on
>   the field; that face-up monster cannot be targeted or destroyed **by
>   your opponent's card effects**, or be destroyed by battle. It cannot
>   attack your opponent directly. When this card leaves the field,
>   destroy that monster. When that monster leaves the field, destroy this
>   card.

Since Safe Zone explicitly mentions protection from your opponents card effects, it will indeed not protect your monster from a second Safe Zone you control, equiped to it.

For your second question, the same logic applies. The monster may not be under your control, they are still your Safe Zone. So yes, all 3 cards will be destroyed.